# Fancybox 2 hashtag linking not showing title attribute

Tags: jquery, title, hashtag, fancybox-2

Im using fancybox 2, and i have successfully created hash tag links to my content, but when i click to go to that content from, for example a search page, it displays all the fancybox content but not the title. Im gussing this is because im not clicking the anchor tag that has the title="" atribute.

Is there any way to get this title from the anchor without clicking it?

my code looks something like this:

```
<a class="library-content-link lightbox" href="#main-document" title="Main Document"></a>
```

js:

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;

if(window.location.hash) {
    $(thisHash).fancybox({
        width       : 640,
        height      : 380,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        openSpeed   : 300,
        closeSpeed  : 300,
    }).trigger('click');
}

$(".lightbox").fancybox({
    width       : 640,
    height      : 380,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    openSpeed   : 300,
    closeSpeed  : 300,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (or not) you followed my post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254290/1055987

I guess your html is missing the `ID` that should be equal to the `href` .... something like

```
<a id="main-document" class="library-content-link lightbox" href="#main-document" title="Main Document"></a>
```

... so you will be binding both selectors to fancybox, the `ID` (the `hash`) and the `class`; both now have the same `title` attribute.